# Truncate text to fit container's fixed height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of *fixed height* boxes containing text. The box widths have percent values.

The text is truncated using **[this piece](https://boylesoftware.com/blog/truncating-text-responsively/)** of jquery.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.noOverflow = function(ellipsis) {
    if (typeof ellipsis === 'undefined') {
      ellipsis = '';
    }
    return this.each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      if (typeof this.overflow_text === 'undefined') {
        // store initial text as a property of the current element
        // in order to reuse it if the container is resized
        this.overflow_text = {
          originalText: el.text()
        }
      }
      // create a hidden "puppet" for better user experience
      var t = $(this.cloneNode(true)).hide().css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'width': 'auto',
        'height': 'auto',
        'overflow': 'visible',
        'max-width': 'inherit',
        'max-height': 'inherit'
      });
      el.after(t);
      var text = this.overflow_text.originalText;
      t.text(text + "");
      // use the puppet to try for the proper text length, removing characters one by one
      // until the puppet will be of designed size
      while (text.length > 0 && (t.width() > el.width() || t.height() > el.height())) {
        text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
        t.text(text + ellipsis);
      }
      el.text(t.text());
      // get rid of the puppet
      t.remove();
    });

  };
})(jQuery);

function updateCutoff() {
  $('.txt').noOverflow('...');
}
updateCutoff();
$(window).resize(updateCutoff);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.txt {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 3.75em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit fugiat</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur est laborum.</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that the text does not fill the entire height of the boxes, even though there is plenty of text to do so. The text stays on *one line*.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Try adding `word-wrap: break-word;` to your `wrapper` class.

Comment: It happens because you set a fixed `height` and `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this piece of code `t.width() > el.width()`. It only accounts for width once, however, with you having multiple lines, you will need to account for all the lines. Hence, you will need to fix this part.

For illustration purpose, I have changed it to `t.width() > 3 * el.width()`

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.noOverflow = function(ellipsis) {
    if (typeof ellipsis === 'undefined') {
      ellipsis = '';
    }
    return this.each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      if (typeof this.overflow_text === 'undefined') {
        // store initial text as a property of the current element
        // in order to reuse it if the container is resized
        this.overflow_text = {
          originalText: el.text()
        }
      }
      // create a hidden "puppet" for better user experience
      var t = $(this.cloneNode(true)).hide().css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'width': 'auto',
        'height': 'auto',
        'overflow': 'visible',
        'max-width': 'inherit',
        'max-height': 'inherit'
      });
      el.after(t);
      var text = this.overflow_text.originalText;
      t.text(text + "");
      // use the puppet to try for the proper text length, removing characters one by one
      // until the puppet will be of designed size
      while (text.length > 0 && (t.width() > 3 * el.width() || t.height() > el.height())) {
        text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
        t.text(text + ellipsis);
      }
      el.text(t.text());
      // get rid of the puppet
      t.remove();
    });

  };
})(jQuery);

function updateCutoff() {
  $('.txt').noOverflow('...');
}
updateCutoff();
$(window).resize(updateCutoff);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.txt {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 3.75em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit fugiat</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur est laborum.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change while condition  `(text.length > 0 && (t.width() < el.width() || t.height() >= el.height()))`

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.noOverflow = function(ellipsis) {
    if (typeof ellipsis === 'undefined') {
      ellipsis = '';
    }
    return this.each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      if (typeof this.overflow_text === 'undefined') {
        // store initial text as a property of the current element
        // in order to reuse it if the container is resized
        this.overflow_text = {
          originalText: el.text()
        }
      }
      // create a hidden "puppet" for better user experience
      var t = $(this.cloneNode(true)).hide().css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'width': 'auto',
        'height': 'auto',
        'overflow': 'visible',
        'max-width': 'inherit',
        'max-height': 'inherit'
      });
      el.after(t);
      var text = this.overflow_text.originalText;
      t.text(text + "");
      // use the puppet to try for the proper text length, removing characters one by one
      // until the puppet will be of designed size
      while (text.length > 0 && (t.width() < el.width() || t.height() >= el.height())) {
        text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
        t.text(text + ellipsis);
      }
      el.text(t.text());
      // get rid of the puppet
      t.remove();
    });

  };
})(jQuery);

function updateCutoff() {
  $('.txt').noOverflow('...');
}
updateCutoff();
$(window).resize(updateCutoff);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.txt {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 3.75em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit fugiat</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="txt">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur est laborum .</span>
</div>
```